# Include Django variable into a JQuery Code

Tags: jquery, django

I have a JQuery code using a pagination plugin, Here is the code :

```
$('#demo').pagination({
    dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 195],
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        // template method of yourself
        var html = template(data);
        dataContainer.html(html);
    }
})
```

But here I want to make the dataSource of a list of customers that is stocked in my database

Answer (score 0):

You can render the data as json on the template from the views.py file..

```
dataset = {'data':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
context = {'data':json.dumps(dataset)}
return render(request, 'path/template-name.html', context)
```

Then read the dataset from the template using java script which will return the dataset as a javascript object

```
const dataset = JSON.parse("{{data|safe}}");
```